# Python Pandas - Using to_sql creates tables and columns with names as strings

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, pandas

When using pandas.to_sql in Python and writing to a PostgreSQL DB, the tables and columns that are created require " " when calling them in the database.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost:5432/Database')

deptDF.to_sql("Departments", engine, if_exists = "replace")
```

Then when I go to PostgreSQL to call the tables, I have to use exactly:

```
SELECT * FROM "Departments"
```

It can be quite annoying, especially with columns.  Any idea how to make the table and column names send w/o needing the ""?

Thanks

Comment: Don't capitalize the table name. It'll still quote the name (i.e. `create table "departments" ...`) but since PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lower case, you'll be able to say `select * from departments` and `select * from Departments` without causing any problems. Of course, if something expects the table name to be in title case then you're out of luck.

Comment: @muistooshort you can post that as an answer! (only, when not using upper case, sqlalchemy will not quote the name, but as you say, it does not matter in that case)

Comment: @joris But I don't know how that will play with the rest of the stuff so I'm not comfortable answering. Some frameworks like tables and columns to be named in certain ways. You're welcome to flesh it out into an answer if you know your way around the Python and Pandas stuff (as your tags suggest).