# Python: Why are the column names in PostgreSQL table wrapped in double quotes?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, etl

Question: I am trying to move the data from one table in SQL Server to another table in Postgresql. The ETL process looks like this:

```
def transfer_data():
    sql = """SELECT TOP(100) * FROM LoanAgreements"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, lms_conn)
    df.to_sql(PG_TABLE, engine, schema=PG_SCHEMA, if_exists='replace', index=False)

def get_data():
    sql = """SELECT LoanAgreementID FROM rileys_schema.test1"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
    return df
```

After transferring the data to Postgresql as test1, when I attempt to query from it, I get an error saying that the column doesn't exist. It seems as though I have to specify the column names wrapped in double quotation marks for the query to execute. Is there a way around this?

Error looks like this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "loanagreementid" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT LoanAgreementID FROM rileys_schema.test1
               ^
 [SQL: 'SELECT LoanAgreementID FROM rileys_schema.test1']
```

Comment: Maybe the quotes are being read as being part of the string? Have your etl look for quotes and remove them?

Comment: When you do a print(df.columns), the double quotes don't appear

Comment: and when you do df.loc[0,'column']? does it require that you do df.loc[0,'"coloumn"']

Comment: Nope. This is a SQL issue I believe. The column names are normal when using Pandas.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, mixed case column names created as such require quoting, so I'm guessing pandas' `to_sql()` created them so. A loosely related Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891746/python-pandas-using-to-sql-creates-tables-and-columns-with-names-as-strings). And as @univerio said, provide a [mcve]. What does your dataframe look like during transfer? What are `PG_TABLE` and `PG_SCHEMA` (guessable, but we shouldn't have to guess)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to double-quote the "LoanAgreementID" column name. Your `CREATE TABLE` statement probably did (especially if you generated your schema with a framework), so in that case you have a `LoanAgreementID` column as you expect. However, unquoted names in queries are automatically lowercased so you are actually searching for a column named `loanagreementid`. Postgres is case-sensitive about object names unless they're quoted, so it can't find it.

Surround the `LoanAgreementID` and `LoanAgreements` names in your query with double-quotes and they should work. Or you could change those names to snake_case in the database (more idiomatic for Postgres, potentially less so elsewhere); it's up to you.